# How to wire 2 ton ac blower for shop fan?

Tags: blower, capacitor

[image]

This is the blower I'm trying to be able to plug in. Capacitor is already connected.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the nameplate label on the blower motor please?

Answer (score 1):

As @Jim Stewart 7 wrote, you will need in most cases to block either the fans inlet or outlet to control the amount of air through the fan. Too much air will overload the motor and burn it up. I have always found it easier to restrict the fan's inlet. You will need a meter to read the amperage draw that is allowed for that motor. The allowable amperage can be found on the motor name plate.

Before you hook that motor up to a 240 volt power supply you need to find out what the voltage needs of that motor are. Running a 120 volt motor on 240 volts would probably "fry" the motor. If that blower & motor came out of a standard gas or oil furnace then it would most likely be a 120 volt motor. If it came out the air handler of a heat pump or an electric furnace, then it could be a 240 volt motor. I would recommend that you first hook up the motor to a 120 volt supply to see if runs normally. If it does, then that is your voltage.

Comment: Interesting thought about the motor over-currenting because of too much air. Does one adjust the restriction until the motor is drawing the nameplate amps?

Comment: @Triplefault, The answer is YES. A direct drive motor will in most cases over amp the motor if there is no resistance to the air flow. In the furnace specs, they show how much air the blower will flow through a certain resistance. If the resistance is too low you can correct the over-amperage by increasing the HP of the motor .

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few blower-turned-shop-fans in my years in a cabinet shop. They work well, there's a lot of movable air through those blowers.

In my experience there has always been a wiring and voltage diagram on the side of the motor. One may be on the side of your motor.

The motor may be two-speed, with one wire as common and the other two are low- and high-speed. Common goes to neutral, low or high goes to power (one or the other, not both at the same time). I won't guess on the colors, better to see the diagram.

Try removing the motor from the case. You may have to unbolt the blower blade from the motor shaft. There should at least be a model number for the motor you can web-search, if there is no wiring diagram.

Check the required motor voltage, too, and provide compatible power. A 120V motor will die on 240V, and a 240V motor won't spin fast enough on 120V & might die too.

Whichever power wire you choose to connect, cap the other wire safely, as it will have line voltage on it.

One thing to consider: have that fan case clamped down when you power the motor up. Those blowers have some torque and the case will roll itself around.

Comment: Some of these fans are designed to work with a restriction on the Inlet side and backpressure on the outlet.. If such fans are powered with no restriction on the inlet, they will overspeed and be damaged. It may be that restriction on the outlet would suffice but I don't know what works in practice.

Comment: Ok I can run a 240 line. Plenty of room in my box.. and I looked on the side of the motor and seen no wire diagram

Comment: Is there a name plate showing voltage and current, model number, manufacturer, etc? It may be hidden under the clamps. Did you remove the motor so it can be seen all over?